# Are there any practical applications for the format %n in printf/scanf family?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

```
int x;
printf("hello %n World\n", &x);
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Comment: It's interesting that this was closed, because there is an existing answer.  This was asked and answered in 2008.  The one that it is linked to is from 2010.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not so useful for `printf()`, but it can be very useful for `sscanf()`, especially if you're parsing a string in multiple iterations.  `fscanf()` and `scanf()` automatically advance their internal pointers by the amount of input read, but `sscanf()` does not.  For example:

```
char stringToParse[256];
...
char *curPosInString = stringToParse;  // start parsing at the beginning
int bytesRead;
while(needsParsing())
{
    sscanf(curPosInString, "(format string)%n", ..., &bytesRead);  // check the return value here
    curPosInString += bytesRead;  // Advance read pointer
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Depends what you mean by practical. There are always other ways to accomplish it (print into a string buffer with s[n]printf and calculate the length, for example).

However

```
int len;
char *thing = "label of unknown length";
char *value = "value value value"
char *value2="second line of value";
printf ("%s other stuff: %n", thing, &len);
printf ("%s\n%*s, value, len, value2);
```

should produce

```
label of unknown length other stuff: value value value
                                     second line of value
```

(although untested, I'm not near a C compiler)

Which is just about practical as a way of aligning things, but I wouldn't want to see it in code. There are better ways of doing it.

Comment: Apart from the missing semicolon and closing quote, this doesn't work as indicated because the total width of %*s (including value2) is set to len, not the number of initial spaces. So you'll either have to add strlen(value2) to len or use something like printf("%s\n%*s%s",value,len,"",value2).

Comment: @mweerden, thanks, that will teach me to write things like this on the train (I should have used a right-aligned example, which would have worked :)) The idea is still clear, I hope. And it's still too "clever" for real code.

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly esoteric.  If you need to replace a placeholder in the generated string later you might want to remember an index into the middle of the string, so that you don't have to either save the original printf parameter or parse the string.

Answer (score 1):

It could possibly be used as a quick way to get the lengths of various substrings.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int col10 = (10 - 1);
    int col25 = (25 - 1);

    int pos1 = 0;
    int pos2 = 0;

    printf("    5    10   15   20   25   30\n");

    printf("%s%n%*s%n%*s\n",                     "fried", 
                            &pos1, col10 - pos1, "green",   
                            &pos2, col25 - pos2, "tomatos");


    printf("    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^\n");

    printf("%d %d\n", pos1, pos2);
    printf("%d %d\n", col10 - pos1, col25 - pos2);

    return 0;
}
```

I am missing something here for sure.  Tomatos is too far to the right.

Comment: The problem is that you can't use the values that get assigned to pos1 and pos2 in the same call to printf. All arguments are evaluated before the call, meaning that col10-pos1==col10 and col25-pos2==col25. The correct positioning of "green" is accidental. You also made the same mistake as Paul.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something from the VS2005 CRT code:

```
/* if %n is disabled, we skip an arg and print 'n' */
if ( !_get_printf_count_output() )
{
   _VALIDATE_RETURN(("'n' format specifier disabled", 0), EINVAL, -1);
   break;
}
```

which brings up this:

[Dead link removed]

for the following line:

```
printf ("%s other stuff: %n", thing, &len);
```

I'm guessing this is mainly to avoid what @eJames is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

you can call

```
int _get_printf_count_output();
```

to see if %n support is enable, or use

```
int _set_printf_count_output( int enable );
```

to Enable or disable support of the %n format.

from MSDN VS2008